# Click to create tag / label random but start from label-default

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on my button I am trying to create a bootstrap label. But each time I click it should start off at label-default and work through the switch until it gets to the last one the go back to the beginning

As shown on image below it not starting off at label-default

[image]

> **Question** each time I click on the button to create label how can I
>   make sure it does not double up and starts from label-default

DEMO

> [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/JWwQbw)

SCRIPT

```
$(document).on('click', '#category_button', function(e){    

    e.preventDefault();

    //if ($("#label-" + category_name).length  == 0) {

        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

        switch(rand){
          case 1:
            element = 'label-default';
            break;
          case 2:
            element = 'label-primary';
            break;
          case 3:
            element = 'label-success';
            break;
          case 4:
            element = 'label-info';
            break;
          case 5:
            element = 'label-warning';
            break;
        }

        html = '';
        html += '<li id="">';
        html += '<span class="label ' + element + '">';
        html += 'Hello';
        html += '</span>';
        html += '</li>';

        $('.categories ul').append(html);
    //}
});
```

Comment: it is the problem with the random number you are generating. If you want a cycle you could try using some counter

Comment: or you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15585372/2445295

Comment: Than **why** you use `random`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I misunderstood your question, but you are using a random to decide which label to add. If you want an ordered sequence, you should not be using random. Code shown below:

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).on('click', '#category_button', function(e){  
  e.preventDefault();
    switch(counter) {
      case 0:
        element = 'label-default';
        break;
      case 1:
        element = 'label-primary';
        break;
      case 2:
        element = 'label-success';
        break;
      case 3:
        element = 'label-info';
        break;
      case 4:
        element = 'label-warning';
        break;
    }

    counter = (counter + 1) % 5;

    var html = '';
    html += '<li id="">';
    html += '<span class="label ' + element + '">';
    html += 'Hello';
    html += '</span>';
    html += '</li>';

    $('.categories ul').append(html);
  //}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array, `Array.prototype.slice()`, `Array.prototype.splice()` to create a copy of original array. If copied array has `.length` equal to `0` remove first element from array, set the element as `element` value, else get, set random element from copied array as `element` value, repeat procedure.

```js
var arr = ["default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning"];
var label = "label-";
var copy = [];

$(document).on("click", "#category_button", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var element, rand;

  if (!copy.length) {
    copy = arr.slice(0);
    element = copy.splice(0, 1);
  } else {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    element = copy.splice(rand, 1);
  }

  var html = $("<li>", {
    "id":"",
    "html":$("<span>", {
             "class": label.slice(0, -1).concat(" ", label, element),
             "html": label + element
           })
  });

  $(".categories ul").append(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="category_button">click</button>
<div class="categories">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpXryW